# Days of the month do not line up correctly

Tags: java

[Transcript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLFnE.png):

```
Enter month in number between 1 and 12: 4
 April 2020
-----------------------------
 Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
    1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
 26 27 28 29 30
```

Code is below but it needs getStartDay(Year, Month, Day) but when I try to add it at the proper place I get an error that says `PrintCalendar3.java:61: error: cannot find symbol`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintCalendar3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Prompt the user to enter year
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Prompt the user to enter year
    System.out.print("Enter full year (e.g., 2016): ");
    int year = scanner.nextInt();
    // Prompt the user to enter month
    System.out.print("Enter month in number between 1 and 12: ");
    int month = scanner.nextInt();
    // Print calendar for the month of the year
    printMonth(year, month);
  }

  /** Print the calendar for a month in a year */
  static void printMonth(int year, int month) {
    // Print the headings of the calendar
    printMonthTitle(year, month);
    // Print the body of the calendar
    printMonthBody(year, month);
  }

  /** Print the month title, e.g., May, 1999 */
  static void printMonthTitle(int year, int month) {
    System.out.println(" " + getMonthName(month) + " " + year);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    System.out.println(" Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
  }

  /** Get the English name for the month */
  static String getMonthName(int month) {
    String monthName = null;
    switch (month) {
      case 1:
        monthName = "January";
        break;
      case 2:
        monthName = "February";
        break;
      case 3:
        monthName = "March";
        break;
      case 4:
        monthName = "April";
        break;
      case 5:
        monthName = "May";
        break;
      case 6:
        monthName = "June";
        break;
      case 7:
        monthName = "July";
        break;
      case 8:
        monthName = "August";
        break;
      case 9:
        monthName = "September";
        break;
      case 10:
        monthName = "October";
        break;
      case 11:
        monthName = "November";
        break;
      case 12:
        monthName = "December";
    }
    return monthName;
  }

  /** Print month body */
  static void printMonthBody(int year, int month) {
    // Get start day of the week for the first date in the month
    int startDay = getStartDay(year, month);
    // Get number of days in the month
    int numberOfDaysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysInMonth(year, month);
    // Pad space before the first day of the month
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < startDay; i++) System.out.print(" ");
    for (i = 1; i <= numberOfDaysInMonth; i++) {
      if (i < 10) System.out.print(" " + i); else System.out.print(" " + i);
      if ((i + startDay) % 7 == 0) System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  /** Get the start day of the first day in a month */
  static int getStartDay(int year, int month) {
    // Get total number of days since 1/1/1800
    int startDay1800 = 3;
    int totalNumberOfDays = getTotalNumberOfDays(year, month);
    // Return the start day
    return (totalNumberOfDays + startDay1800) % 7;
  }

  /** Get the total number of days since January 1, 1800 */
  static int getTotalNumberOfDays(int year, int month) {
    int total = 0;
    // Get the total days from 1800 to year - 1
    for (int i = 1800; i < year; i++) if (isLeapYear(i)) total =
      total + 366; else total = total + 365;
    // Add days from Jan to the month prior to the calendar month
    for (int i = 1; i < month; i++) total =
      total + getNumberOfDaysInMonth(year, i);
    return total;
  }

  /** Get the number of days in a month */
  static int getNumberOfDaysInMonth(int year, int month) {
    if (
      month == 1 ||
      month == 3 ||
      month == 5 ||
      month == 7 ||
      month == 8 ||
      month == 10 ||
      month == 12
    ) return 31; else if (
      month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11
    ) return 30; else if (month == 2) return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
    return 0; // If month is incorrect
  }

  /** Determine if it is a leap year */
  static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have _Java_ confused with _JavaScript_.

Comment: Instead of using switch to get the month name, use a **string-array** with all the months in it. then you can simply use `months[month+1]` where months is the array and month is numerical value for month

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example maybe for January and I can take it from there? That will help me know how to do it and make sure it is right. Thanks Andy

Comment: Which is line 61 in your code?  And what symbol cannot be found?  (The 2nd question is meant to point out that you truncated the message `PrintCalendar3.java:61: error: cannot find symbol:`. What comes after `symbol:`?).

Comment: You need to ensure each digit group take up 3 characters in width

Comment: To get the days of the months to line up, you need to make them all the same width. One tool you could use is to use a tab (`\t`) before each day of week abbreviated name and before each day of month, which would left align. But, it's better to study a [number formatting tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the *[printf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))* method.

The *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* class JavaDoc contains the full list of format specifiers.

You can specify a width, to align the values.

Firstly,  since your week days are 3 letters, separated by spaces, you'll want to change the initial *for-loop* to provide 4 spaces, rather than one.

```java
for (i = 0; i < startDay; i++)
    System.out.print("    ");
```

Then, for the subsequent *for-loop*, you can use the *printf* method.
By default, the content will be right-justified.

```java
for (i = 1; i <= numberOfDaysInMonth; i++)
{
    if (i < 10)
        System.out.printf("%4s", i);
    else
        System.out.printf("%4s", i);
    if ((i + startDay) % 7 == 0)
        System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
Enter full year (e.g., 2016): 2023
Enter month in number between 1 and 12: 6
 June 2023
-----------------------------
 Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
                   1   2   3
   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
  25  26  27  28  29  30
```

Additionally, you can center the month *name* with the following.
I'm using *29* ÷ *2*, since the width of the calendar text is *29*.

```java
/** Print the month title, e.g., May, 1999 */
static void printMonthTitle(int year, int month) {
    String title = getMonthName(month);
    int offset = (29 / 2) - (title.length() / 2);
    System.out.printf("%" + offset + "s%s%n", "", title);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    System.out.println(" Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
}
```

```
Enter full year (e.g., 2016): 2023
Enter month in number between 1 and 12: 6
            June
-----------------------------
 Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
                   1   2   3
   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
  25  26  27  28  29  30
```

Comment: I got the following errors on this:

Comment: Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
            Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%4s'
        at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2580)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:974)
        at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:870)
        at PrintCalendar4.printMonthBody(PrintCalendar4.java:87)
        at PrintCalendar4.printMonth(PrintCalendar4.java:23)
        at PrintCalendar4.main(PrintCalendar4.java:15).

Comment: @AniketPandey, possibly something they changed in a newer version of Java?  It works fine with version 20.

Comment: @AniketPandey, well, version 20, _"... It works fine with version 20."_.

Comment: @AniketPandey, I'm running it here, with Java 20, and it works fine.  I even provided the output, in the code.

Comment: @Nicole, you are possibly using _"%4s" + i_, make sure it is _"%4s", i_.

Comment: Also, please remove all unnecessary comments so as to not confuse others. I'll do the same.

Comment: To left-justify the dates, you can use `%-4s`, the **-** (minus sign) align the modifier output to left. Also, your `%s` works because  the string modifier has implicit type conversion from int or smallInt to string.

Answer (score 0):

Added `monthsArray` to get month-name instead of a `getMonthName` function. Your spacing is wrong for dates. Each column you have is 4 characters long(3 for week-day and 1 space after) hence you need to have 4 spaces for each date. Example: if date is "1", you need 3 spaces before it to make the total equal to 4 characters. Similarly 2 spaces before two-digit dates and 4 spaces for empty blocks at the start of calendar. Check the comments I have added in code for spaces.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrintCalendar3 {

  static String[] monthsArray = {
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Prompt the user to enter year
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Prompt the user to enter year
    System.out.print("Enter full year (e.g., 2016): ");
    int year = scanner.nextInt();
    // Prompt the user to enter month
    System.out.print("Enter month in number between 1 and 12: ");
    int month = scanner.nextInt();
    // Print calendar for the month of the year
    printMonth(year, month);
  }

  /** Print the calendar for a month in a year */
  static void printMonth(int year, int month) {
    // Print the headings of the calendar
    printMonthTitle(year, month);
    // Print the body of the calendar
    printMonthBody(year, month);
  }

  /** Print the month title, e.g., May, 1999 */
  static void printMonthTitle(int year, int month) {
    System.out.println(" " + monthsArray[month - 1] + " " + year);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    System.out.println(" Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat");
  }

  /** Print month body */
  static void printMonthBody(int year, int month) {
    // Get start day of the week for the first date in the month
    int startDay = getStartDay(year, month);
    // Get number of days in the month
    int numberOfDaysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysInMonth(year, month);
    // Pad space before the first day of the month
    int i = 0;
    //4 spaces as month name has three char and a space after them
    for (i = 0; i < startDay; i++) System.out.printf("%4s","");
    for (i = 1; i <= numberOfDaysInMonth; i++) {
      //3 spaces for single digit
      if (i < 10) System.out.printf("%4d", i);
      //2 spaces for double digit
      else System.out.printf("%4d", i);
      if ((startDay + i) % 7 == 0) System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  /** Get the start day of the first day in a month */
  static int getStartDay(int year, int month) {
    // Get total number of days since 1/1/1800
    int startDay1800 = 3;
    int totalNumberOfDays = getTotalNumberOfDays(year, month);
    // Return the start day
    return (totalNumberOfDays + startDay1800) % 7;
  }

  /** Get the total number of days since January 1, 1800 */
  static int getTotalNumberOfDays(int year, int month) {
    int total = 0;
    // Get the total days from 1800 to year - 1
    for (int i = 1800; i < year; i++) if (isLeapYear(i)) total =
      total + 366; else total = total + 365;
    // Add days from Jan to the month prior to the calendar month
    for (int i = 1; i < month; i++) total =
      total + getNumberOfDaysInMonth(year, i);
    return total;
  }

  /** Get the number of days in a month */
  static int getNumberOfDaysInMonth(int year, int month) {
    if (
      month == 1 ||
      month == 3 ||
      month == 5 ||
      month == 7 ||
      month == 8 ||
      month == 10 ||
      month == 12
    ) return 31; else if (
      month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11
    ) return 30; else if (month == 2) return isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28;
    return 0; // If month is incorrect
  }

  /** Determine if it is a leap year */
  static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: The days still do not line up on this one

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you for your help. The second part wants a 12 month calendar for the whole year. Here is the code and I am having the same issue with the days lining up. I will try to fix it like you did but may have challenges.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `java.time` API as it knows all the names:

```
public static void printCalendarForMonth(LocalDate date) {
    DayOfWeek firstDayOfMonth = date.withDayOfMonth(1).getDayOfWeek();
    int dayOfWeekIndex = firstDayOfMonth.getValue();
    DateTimeFormatter dayFmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE");
    System.out.printf(" %s %s%n", date.getMonth(), date.getYear());
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
    Stream.of(DayOfWeek.values()).map(d -> dayFmt.format(d).toUpperCase())
            .forEach(d -> System.out.printf("%4s", d));
    System.out.println();
    int start = 1 - dayOfWeekIndex;
    int counter = 1;
    for (int i = start; i < date.lengthOfMonth(); i++) {
        if (i < 0) {
            System.out.printf("%4s", " ");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%4d", i + 1);
        }
        if (counter % 7 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```